# Update Terminal Prompt Hostname "On The Fly" without reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, prompt

I am not asking how to change a hostname and I am not asking how to update a terminal prompt. What I am asking is how to update a terminal prompt from a bash script so that when the user exits the script that the terminal prompt is updated and the user does not have to source ~/.bashrc from the command line or reboot to receive the new updated terminal prompt.
I have tried several things with export and source but nothing seems to work.
This is my simple script:

```
 while [[ $newhostname = "" ]]; do
   printf "Use of dash \"-\" is allowed\n"
   read -p "Enter New Hostname: "  newhostname
   # Sanitize and un-tint user input
   if [[ "$newhostname" =~ ^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][\_a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][\_A-Za-z0-9\-]{0,61}[A-Za-z0-9])$  && $$
     printf "\nNew Hostname \"$newhostname\" Passes Format Criteria\n"
     hostnamectl set-hostname $newhostname
     export HOSTNAME=$newhostname
     echo 'PS1='\"\\u@${newhostname}\\w# \" >> ~/.bashrc
     source ~/.bashrc
     printf "Hostname was updated to \"$newhostname\"\n\n"
     export PS1="\u@$HOSTNAME:\w# "
   else
     printf "\nNew Hostname \"$newhostname\" Does not Pass Format Criteria allowed for DNS domain name labels\n"
     printf "http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/hostname.5.html\n\n"
     printf "\033[1;91m ==>> Please Try Again <<==\033[1;33m\n\n"
     newhostname=""
   fi
 done # End While
```

Maybe it is not possible to change or update the system ENV from a bash script? Maybe it's impossible and I need to quit trying to do it?
Any Ideas?

Comment: You can't. A shell has it's own copy of the environment.

Comment: Is there possibly a way to restart a system service or create a system service that can be restarted to update the terminal prompt?

Comment: Run your script with `. ./script.sh`?

Comment: What about the possibility of using cron? I'll try ./ and see

Comment: Nope... crontab doesn't help.....

Comment: Cyrus, that was useful and I needed to cd to the /usr/bin/ to use it as the system reported it's not in the path. I couldn't start it with /usr/bin/. ./script.sh either. It did the job but it has it's baggage needing to cd and I discovered if I use exit 0 in the script it closes the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PROMPT_COMMAND](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html) bash variable to update the `PS1` variable every time before the prompt is drawn.

This way, you are not propagating the changes from your script back to the ENV (which is impossible). Instead, you are making bash check the hostname on every prompt redraw.

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# set the prompt to whatever you want 
# but instead of hostname (\h) use `$dynamic_hostname` variable
PS1='\$ \u@${dynamic_hostname} : \w # '

# prompt command will update the `$dynamic_hostname` variable 
# to the latest value before each prompt redraw
PROMPT_COMMAND='dynamic_hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname)'

# this is just to make sure that `$dynamic_hostname` is not unset at any time
realtime_hostname=$(cat /etc/hostname)
```

The hostname displayed in your prompt will update on every redraw based on `/etc/hostname`.

Of course, you could update the hostname based on any other file or command.